# How to immediately redraw a Label (NSTextField) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa

I'm dealing with a synchronous task which takes a little time to complete (about 1-2 sec).

Before that task begins, I'd like to update a Label's text:

```
label.stringValue = "Loading"
doMyTask() // This freezes everything for a moment
```

However, the text only appears when my task is done, making the `Loading` message totally useless.

So, is there a reason to force my Label to update its text before the task will begin?
This, for example, is the way of achieving this in C# while working with Windows Forms:

```
label.Text = "Loading";
label.Refresh();
```

I tried `label.setNeedsDisplay()` as well as `label.updateLayer()` and that didn't work out

Thank you.

Comment: `doMyTask` is blocking the main thread, freezing all UI updates. Never block the main thread. Use Dispatch or the new async/await to move that blocking work off the main thread.

Comment: Thank you, I just hope there is another way to achieve this. Main thread only blocks for a moment and that's not noticeable at all, so I thought just forcing the label to redraw would be a better approach.

Comment: "only blocks for a moment" that's not acceptable, you should rework that.